# SQL Server COALESCE bit compared to an int

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I have a situation where I am passing a bit datatype into a COALESCE. Then setting that = 0 to check if it equals 0. The problem is, that is not working!

(Please note that I am not authorized to change the datatype of any columns)

This is what I have:

```
SELECT Meters.ID, Consumption, Charge
    FROM Data (nolock)
    JOIN Meters
        ON Data.MeterID = Meters.ID

    WHERE COALESCE(Processed, 0) = 0
```

The idea behind Processed is that, if the data were processed than it should 1 so I do not want to process them again.

//Processed is a column in the Data table that is type bit. My Joins are 100% correct cause I ran them without the Where and execute with no problems, the problem is when I add that where! Even though that Processed column has 1, 0, NULL values.... It does not return anything! Can anybody suggest a solution? Thank you.

Comment: i dont understand why you use coalesce if you are only looking for the non processed ones which is controlled by a bit type.

should simply be  -> where processed <> 1

Comment: Good point, that is because I do not want any NULLS.

Comment: then you can where isnull(processed,0) <> 1

Answer (score 0):

```
where processed is null or processed = 0
```

is the logical equivalent expresion, I don't figue why COALESCE is not working